# Adding multiple extensions to PHP.INI

Tags: php

I have two extensions I want to add. Do I add these separately like:

```
extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Or are they added like an array?

```
extension=php_ftp.dll,php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Line by line. One line for each extension you want to enable. 
After enabling them, restart your server, and check if they are loaded in php.ini file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Or from command line:

```
drive:\\path\to\php\executable\php.exe -i
```